# Understanding concurrency and GPU as a limited resource

Tags: cuda, opencl, theory, gpgpu

With CPU and memory it's simple.

A process has a large virtual address space, which is partially mapped into physical memory. When the current process attempts to access a page that is not in physical memory, OS steps in, chooses a page to swap (e.g. with Round Robin), swaps it into disc, then reads the required page from the swap, and the control is returned back to the process. This is straightforward, because the process cannot continue without having that page.

GPU kernels is a different story.

Let's consider a usecase:
A high-priority [cpu] process, namely **X**, makes a call to kernel (which is a blocking call). At this moment, it is reasonable for OS to switch contexts and give the CPU to a different process, namely **Z**. For the sake of example, let the process **Z** also do something heavy with the GPU.

Now, what does the GPU driver do? Does it stop the kernel that belongs to [higher prioritized] **X**? Does it inform OS that **Z** isn't prioritized enough to offload kernels of **X**? In general, what happens when two processes need GPU resources, but the available GPU memory is sufficient to serve only one of them at a time?

Comment: Even a single data-feeding-thread makes cpu cores unavailable for some time for opencl if you gave the opencl context a full-cpu. You can use device-fission of opencl to make a full cpu into separate cores to get rid of this. For now, maybe gtx titan and r9-290x may be able to do device fission. Tested HD7870 drivers' opencl on FX8150 and it choked. When I used device fission to separate 7 cores, it flowed like a fluid. If you dont use waitevent for gpu then kernel is not blocking for cpu.

Comment: I heard a HD7870 can do as many independent tasks as its compute-unit number(20) separately in a folding@home site. Actually two or three compute-unit feeding can be done by a single core as they wrote.

Comment: In CUDA: 1. kernel calls are non-blocking.  2. you can have multiple kernels launched, and executing sequentially (or possibly in parallel), even if issued from multiple threads, and they will execute according to the GPU scheduler's rules 3. if you attempt to allocate more memory than the device can support, the allocation will fail and return a runtime API error.  So you will not even get to the point of launching the kernel that depends on that data.

Comment: Let's suppose the GPU has 1GB of RAM. Process A needs 700 Mb to complete its task, Process B needs 700 Mb to complete its task. What would happen?

Comment: (I mean the device has enough for a process, but not for two such processes at once)

Comment: before the each process starts, the memory has to be explicitly allocated, (using `cudaMalloc` for CUDA).  The first attempt (by Process A on the CPU) to do a `cudaMalloc` would succeed for 700MB.  The second attempt (by Process B) (assuming the first had not been freed using `cudaFree`) would fail.  If you pay attention to these API errors, your code should never get to the point of the kernel launch associated with the second allocation, in Process B.

Answer (score 5):

CUDA GPUs context-switch cooperatively at a coarse granularity (think "memcpy" or "kernel launch"). If there is enough memory for both contexts, the hardware is happy to cooperatively context switch between them at a slight performance cost. (But because it's cooperative, long-running kernels will interfere with other kernels' execution.)

Modern GPUs do support virtual memory (i.e. memory protection through address translation), but they do NOT support demand paging.  That means every piece of memory accessible to the GPU (device memory and mapped pinned memory) must be physically present and mapped after allocation.

The Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) introduced in Windows Vista does paging at a very coarse granularity. The driver is required to track which "memory objects" are needed to execute a given command buffer, and the OS ensures that they are present.  The OS can swap them out when not needed. The wrinkle with CUDA is that since pointers can be stored, all memory objects associated with the CUDA address space must be resident in order to run a CUDA kernel.  So the paging doesn't work as well for CUDA as it does for graphics applications, which WDDM was designed to run.